# Toolbar in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-toolbar

In our app, we have a few fragments that can be shown either as fullscreen fragments or as dialog fragments. These fragments inherit from `DialogFragment` and we make sure to instantiate them correctly depending the mode the app is executed in (either fullscreen or dialog).

We thought about adding some extra functionality to some of these dialog fragments after the latest changes in the `Toolbar` widget were introduced in the support library with Lollipop. The idea is to have the type of options menu we would normally have in an ordinary fragment (i.e. the options menu inflated after `onCreateOptionsMenu` is executed) present in our subclasses of `DialogFragment` ONLY when these are visualized as dialogs. In short: when the fragments are shown in fullscreen mode we inflate a traditional options menu, and when the fragments are shown as dialogs we would like to have the same options menu inflated but using the new toolbar widget in standalone mode.

I followed the steps from http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html and I managed to "activate" the toolbar, but it seems the menu is not inflated - see attached screenshots (picture one fragment in fullscreen mode, and picture two in dialog mode).

Is it even possible to inflate an options menu with the new toolbar in a `DialogFragment`?

[image: fullscreen mode][image: dialog mode]

Comment: Toolbar is not suppose to be in a dialog, it is suppose to be part of your activities layout. that is a very confusing interface you want to have

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Is it even possible to inflate an options menu with the new toolbar in
>   a DialogFragment?

first of all your design is ok and toolbar is supposed to be used every where lets have a look at this from **Chris Banes** google engineer [link](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/):

```
// Set an OnMenuItemClickListener to handle menu item clicks
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
        new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle the menu item
                return true;
            }
});

// Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_toolbar_menu);
```

and also android developer toolbar standalone sample:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: Thanks. I was 100% positive it could be done, as the picture Chris Banes attached to his post proves it. I found my mistake after reading his post for the 5th time :-)

Comment: About the app (which is found here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.iosched ) , here's a screenshot: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Xwh9uUA-TvDYAFtadcPrR578GJGxbZu5Z2KuUv5U0v3QqzvQzpHR9nuDMUhMsPgVbS8=h900

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu`, which receives an `inflater`, is perfectly reasonable to override in a `DialogFragment` - but of course, call `inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu)` and you get absolutely NOTHING.  You HAVE to use `Toolbar`'s `inflateMenu()` method. WHY? Every single turn in Android is another lesson in complete madness.

Comment: Now you can use Material Design's **MaterialToolbar** (https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android) which extends Toolbar and may make your life easier.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, DialogFragment has setHasOptions() function. Define the toolbar in the layout of your dialog and use it as if it is in an activity. A toolbar doesnt mind being in an activity or a fragment or a dialog fragment.......

Be sure that you use

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true) in onActivityCreated method....
```

Then, as usual override

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
}
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: How can I use a `Toolbar` in standalone mode if I don't wire it and inflate a menu? Your solution simply overrides the default options menu specified in the host activity. It doesn't make a dialog fragment have a toolbar

Comment: This doesn't work. Instead it handles the toolbar of the activity itself.

Comment: How can I hide the toolbar from dialogfragment?